# Web Scraping using python(Beautifulsoup)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am just started learning web scraping using python `Beautifulsoup` and requests library and using Pycharm tool.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
result1 = requests.get("https://www.grainger.com/")
print('result1 is '+ str(result1.status_code))
```

While I am using this website its keeps on loading and if I use `google.com` it's giving output.

I wonder why I didn't get output for the above website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get status `200` from this site, specify `User-Agent` HTTP header:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:81.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0'}

result1 = requests.get("https://www.grainger.com/", headers=headers)

print('result1 is '+ str(result1.status_code))
```

Prints:

```
result1 is 200
```

The reason why this is works is because some sites will ignore requests that don't appear to be made from a web browser.  By default, [requests](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/master/requests/utils.py#L805) uses the `User-Agent` `python-requests`, so the website can tell you are not requesting the website from a web browser.  The reason why your request hangs and eventually times out is likely because their server is ignoring your request.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... there are a couple of things.

1. The website might not exist
2. You're using http instead of https
3. That site blocks scraping (send a user agent header)
4. It might be a problem with requests. Try using a different library.